# I'm trying to configure an element using the 'link text' locateStrategy in a PageObject with Nightwatch

Tags: nightwatch.js

I am trying to use a pageObect that has an element that is located via the 'link text' locate strategy. I can recreate the failure on google.com with their 'Store' link.

`nightwatch v0.9.21`

```
//google page object
module.exports = {
  url: function () {
    return 'https://www.google.com';
  },
  elements: {
    storeLinkText: {
      selector: 'Store',
      locateStrategy: 'link text'
    },
    storeXPath: {
      selector: '//*[@id="hptl"]/a[2]',
      locateStrategy: 'xpath'
    },
    storeDefaultSelector: '#hptl > a:nth-child(2)',
  },
};
```

From the tests:
...

```
// Fails
return client.page.core.google().navigate().then( () => {
  return client.page.core.google().waitForElementPresent('@storeLinkText', 1000);
});

// Passes
return client.page.core.google().navigate().then( () => {
  return client.page.core.google().waitForElementPresent('@storeXPath', 1000);
});

//Passes
return client.page.core.google().navigate().then( () => {
  return client.page.core.google().waitForElementPresent('@storeDefaultSelector', 1000);
});
```

The API says they support 'link text' and 'partial link text' as `locateStrategy` options. https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/wiki/Page-Object-API